# Wordpress for iOS not getting compiled

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, compilation

> Note: I'm not sure if this is the
>   right place to ask this question, but
>   i figured that i might get an obvious
>   or "general" answer... which may help
>   someone else in the future. So, here
>   goes.

I got the copy of WordPress source-code from [here](http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk).

When i first compiled it, i received bunch of these errors:

```
error: CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h: No such file or directory
```

I found the solution to fix this here:

```
http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/511
```

I downloaded the latest copy of plcrashreported, and replaced the existing one. But still, the project is not getting compiled. Here's what i get:

```
Build WordPress of project WordPress with configuration Debug

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WordPress.app/WordPress normal i386
cd /Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/FlurryLib -F/Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/Classes -filelist /Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/build/WordPress.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WordPress.build/Objects-normal/i386/WordPress.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -weak_framework UIKit -lxml2 -licucore -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreData -framework MediaPlayer -framework CFNetwork -lz.1.2.3 -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -framework MessageUI -framework CrashReporter -lFlurry -liconv -o /Users/imauser/Downloads/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WordPress.app/WordPress

ld: warning: duplicate dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReport", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReport in WordPressAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReport in CrashReportViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReporter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReporter in WordPressAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReporter in CrashReportViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, what's going on here? I can't make sense of this. And, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a linker error that probably means that the CrashReporter library path isn't defined in you project settings.

Look for the "Search Paths" section for the entry called "Library Search Paths" and see if this is either set incorrectly, or not set at all.

Comment: "Library Search Paths" is empty for Project Settings! But not for Target Settings. "Library Search Paths" doesn't contain the search path for "CrashReporter.framework" placed in the root directory. Even when i do add the path "$(SRCROOT)/CrashReporter.framework" under "Library Search Paths" and "Framework Search Paths", it doesn't work. Or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Mustafa!

When I do add the path ***$(SRCROOT)/*** under ***Framework Search Path***, it work for me very well.

Hope it can help you!